# How to make a programme executable anywhere in the SHELL

Tags: linux, perl, path

How to make a programme executable in the SHELL

I have git cloned a number of tools into my HOME folder. Now as there are many of them and my query files are located on a different directory, what I need is make a programme executable from everywhere in the SHELL. I have read [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/how-can-i-make-a-program-executable-from-everywhere) but how about Perl and Python scipts. For example, I have a script.pl or script.py file in a folder named scrips. What should I do to make that script run from everywhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Make the scripts executable: `chmod +x $HOME/scrips/*` This needs to be done only once.
2. Add the directory containing the scripts to the `PATH` variable: `export PATH=$HOME/scrips/:$PATH` (Verify the result with `echo $PATH`.) The `export` command needs to be run in every shell session. For convenience, you want to add that command to the `$HOME/.profile` file so it is run automatically for you at log-in time.

Now you can execute `script.pl some-arguments` or `script.py some-arguments` from anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

just type  just type
`export PATH=$PATH:</path/to/file>`
then:
`source ~/.bashrc`
at the command line it will only last for the length of the session.

If you want to change it permanently add
`export PATH=$PATH:</path/to/file>`
to your `~/.bashrc file` . follow this link for more explanation https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3820/401010

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30122477)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind is using Aliases.

So, there should be nothing preventing you from doing e.g.

```
$ alias mycoolscript="python /$HOME/scripts/script.py"
```

Then you could use it like any other shell command:

```
$ mycoolscript https://outlick.com/
```

And this would call your Python program.

You can read more about them [here](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases)

NOTE: The alias wont persist across shell sessions. If you want to add these permanently you can add the alias command to your .bashrc

open $HOME/.bashrc with your favorite text editor and add the line to the bottom

when you are done type

```
$ source $HOME/.bashrc
```

and you can start using the commands

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way is to add your script's directory to the `PATH` environment variable. [Here is an article that describes what the PATH variable is.](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/path-variable)

1. Make the script executable by running `chmod +x <script-name>`
2. Navigate to the the directory where the script is located and  run this command to add the directory consisting your scripts to the PATH `echo export PATH=$(pwd):$PATH >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc` If you are ushing bash as your shell.